# In Jasmine, how does one test a function that uses document.write

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function:

```
var foo = function() {
    document.write( bar() );
};
```

My Jasmine test is:

```
describe('has a method, foo, that', function() {
    it('calls bar', function() {
        spyOn(window, 'bar').andReturn('');
        foo();
        expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

My problem is that the test passes and `foo` document.writes to the page, completely overwriting the page. Is there a good way to test this function?

[A related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248636/how-to-test-internal-functions-which-are-needed-for-internal-purposes-using-ja)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can spy on `document.write`

```
var foo = function () {
  document.write('bar');
};

describe("foo", function () {

  it("writes bar", function () {
    spyOn(document, 'write')
    foo()
    expect(document.write).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bar')
  });
});
```

Comment: Since a global object (document) is spied upon, this can fail other parallel running tests that also test code that uses document.write. In this case make sure to use spyOn(document, 'write').and.callThrough() to let 'write' function as normal.